# Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, simultaneous

I try to understand how multiple commands in a single command line in a batch file work.

```
dir & md folder1 & rename folder1 mainfolder
```

And other case with similar commands, but `&` substituted with `&&`.

```
dir && md folder1 && rename folder1 mainfolder
```

***1. What is the difference between this two cases?***

---

Other thing I want to ask:

One-liner `batch.bat`:

```
dir & md folder1 & rename folder1 mainfolder
```

Multi-liner `batch.bat`:

```
dir
md folder1
rename folder1 mainfolder
```

***2. Are this one-liner and multi-liner equal in terms of batch file procedure?***

---

And one more thing I would like to know:

***3. If I call other batch files from a main.bat, are they run independent and simultaneously? Main batch file does not wait for ending procedures in other batch files? How to do that?***

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`&` between two commands simply results in executing both commands independent on result of first command. The command right of `&` is executed after command left of `&` finished independent on success or error of the previous command, i.e. independent on exit / return value of previous command.

`&&` results in a conditional execution of second command. The second command is executed only if first command was successful which means exited with return code 0.

For an alternate explanation see [Conditional Execution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html).

```
dir & md folder1 & rename folder1 mainfolder
```

is therefore equal

```
dir
md folder1
rename folder1 mainfolder
```

A multiline replacement for

```
dir && md folder1 && rename folder1 mainfolder
```

would be

```
dir
if not errorlevel 1 (
   md folder1
   if not errorlevel 1 (
      rename folder1 mainfolder
   )
)
```

`if not errorlevel 1` means the command before did **not** terminate with an exit code **greater 0**. As the commands `dir` and `md` never exit with a negative value, just with 0 or greater (as nearly all commands and console applications) and value **0** is the exit code for success, this is a correct method to test on successful execution of `dir` and `md`.

Other helpful Stack Overflow topics about `errorlevel`:

- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)
- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)

Care must be taken on mixing unconditional operator `&` with conditional operators like `&&` and `||` because of the execution order is not necessarily the order of the commands on command line.

Example:

```
dir "C:\Users\%UserName%" /AD 2>nul || dir "%UserProfile%" /AD & echo User profile path: "%UserProfile%"
```

This command line is executed as:

```
dir "C:\Users\%UserName%" /AD 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 dir "%UserProfile%" /AD
echo User profile path: "%UserProfile%"
```

The **ECHO** command is always executed independent on result of execution of first **DIR** whereas second **DIR** is executed only if first **DIR** fails like on Windows XP or the user's profile folder is not on drive C: or not in a folder `Users` at all.

It is necessary to use `(` and `)` on executing **ECHO** only if first **DIR** fails after second **DIR** independent on result of second **DIR**.

```
dir "C:\Users\%UserName%" /AD 2>nul || ( dir "%UserProfile%" /AD & echo User profile path: "%UserProfile%" )
```

This command line is executed as:

```
dir "C:\Users\%UserName%" /AD 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    dir "%UserProfile%" /AD
    echo User profile path: "%UserProfile%"
)
```

For the answer on third question see my answer on [How to call a batch file in the parent folder of current batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) where I have explained the differences on running a batch file with command `call` or with command `start` or with none of those two commands from within a batch file.