# Using powershell archive individual files with winrar command line

Tags: powershell, winrar

I am struggling to archive file using PowerShell command with winrar

Folder has some text files `N:\Download`: abc.txt, xyz.txt

i would like to get output: `N:\Download`: abc.rar, xyz.rar and delete the text file after archive.
and how can I set the compressed level maximum?

https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwM.htm

here is my sample script

```
$Source = get-ChildItem -path N:\Download -filter "*.txt"
$Rarfile = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" 
$Dest = "N:\Download"

&$WinRar a $Source.Fullname $Dest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPCommandLineSyntax.htm),

- To delete the files after archiving, use the [-df](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwDF.htm) switch
- To set the compression level use the [-m<n>](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwM.htm) switch

Note, you have defined the full path to the winrar.exe file in variable `$Rarfile`, but later on you use undefined variable `$WinRar`..

If you want to create a .rar file for each source file separately, you will need a loop to be able to construct the output .rar filename

Try

```
$WinRar = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" 
$Dest   = "N:\Download"

(Get-ChildItem -Path 'N:\Download' -Filter '*.txt') | ForEach-Object {
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $Dest -ChildPath ('{0}.rar' -f $_.BaseName)
    & $WinRar a -m4 -df $outFile $($_.Fullname)
    # or use 
    # & $WinRar m -m4 $outFile $($_.Fullname)
}
```

<sup>If you do not want WinRar to include the folder structure of the files, append the [-ep](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwEP.htm) switch to the command</sup>

Comment: The __best__ compression is reached with the switch `-m5` while the switch `-m4` is just for __good__ compression. There could be used also the *WinRAR* command `m` (move) instead of the *WinRAR* command `a` (add) with switch `-df` (delete file/folder). That is explained all in help of *WinRAR* which is installed with *WinRAR* and can be opened in started *WinRAR* by clicking in last menu __Help__ on first item __Help topics__, expanding on first tab __Contents__ the list item __Command line mode__ and read the referenced help pages. That is just for all *WinRAR* users who read never the help.

Comment: I recommend to read also [How to compress each subfolder in a folder into a separate RAR archive using WinRAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936153/3074564) What I wrote in this answer can be used also to compress each file in a folder into a separate archive. There is no PowerShell script needed at all. The task can be done with just a few mouse button clicks in *WinRAR* (seven mouse button clicks after browsing to the directory with the text files).