# How to create a RAR archive with current date in archive file name?

Tags: batch-file, archive, winrar

I have folder `D:\data` with lots of subfolders and files and I want to archive this folder with a batch file to a specified directory with current date added in archive file name, e.g. `F:\11.08.2016_data`.

My command line is so far:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -ep1 -r "data" "D:\data"
```

This command line creates RAR archive file `data.rar` in folder `My Documents`.

How can I add date and change the archiving directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**How to build a *WinRAR* command line?**

1. Start *WinRAR*.
2. Click in menu **Help** on **Help topics**.
3. Click on tab **Contents** on list item **Command line mode**.
4. Click on list item *Command line syntax*, read this help page and copy the bold line into a text editor or into a command prompt window.
5. Click on tab **Contents** on list item **Commands**.
6. Click on list item *Alphabetic commands list* and replace `<command>` in text editor or command prompt window by most suitable command letter for the task.
7. Click on tab **Contents** on list item **Switches**.
8. Click on list item *Alphabetic switches list* and replace `-<switch1> -<switchN>` in text editor or command prompt window by those switches which are useful for the task.
9. Replace the rest of the *WinRAR* command line in text editor or command prompt window by the appropriate file and/or folder names.

**How to build a *RAR* command line?**

1. Open the folder containing the program files of *WinRAR*.
   The standard folders are:
   `%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR`
   `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinRAR`
2. Double click on the file `Rar.txt` to open it. This is the manual for `Rar.exe`, the console version of *WinRAR*.
3. In chapter **RAR command line syntax** the general command line syntax is described which should be used as template for the command to enter in a text editor or in a command prompt window.
4. Next the available commands are listed in alphabetical order with a brief description. One of these commands must be used for the *Rar* command line.
5. Then the list of switches follows, also in alphabetical order and also explained. It is advisable to read about the switches and while reading typing the useful switches for the task in text editor or in command prompt window.
6. Type the rest of the *Rar* command line in text editor or command prompt window, i.e. the file and folder names.

An appropriate *Rar* command line for your task would be:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -y "F:\data_.rar" "D:\data\"
```

The switch `-agYYYY-MM-DD` is responsible for creating in directory `F:\` archive files for example with name `data_2016-08-11.rar`.

It is of course also possible to use:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -agDD.MM.YYYY -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -y "F:\data_.rar" "D:\data\"
```

This command line creates in `F:\` archive files with name `data_11.08.2016.rar`. But this is not advisable as the international date format `YYYY-MM-DD` has the advantage that the files listed alphabetically sorted by name are automatically also listed by date which is not the case with date format `DD.MM.YYYY`.

See the answer on [Simply compress 1 folder in batch with WinRAR command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24401436/3074564) for difference on being specified `D:\data` or `D:\data\` on *Rar* command line.

A `+` must be inserted between `-ag` and date format string for date left to `data` separated with an underscore in archive file name.

Date in international format `YYYY-MM-DD` at beginning of RAR file name:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -ag+YYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -y "F:\_data.rar" "D:\data\"
```

Date in format `DD.MM.YYYY` at beginning of RAR file name:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -ag+DD.MM.YYYY -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -r -y "F:\_data.rar" "D:\data\"
```

Comment: I made an (incremental) rar.exe backup script that searches a whole disk for a specific set of files and then creates a winrar archive with both date (YYYYmmDD) and time (HH.mm_ss) in its name. It also ads a comment file and should work on all localized system environments: https://pastebin.com/Cd1cpyJC. I explained all options the best I could and it should be easy to adjust to your own needs