# How to add a readme file to each subfolder of a folder on compressing them to RAR archive files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rar

I want to write a batch script that add `readme.txt` file to some directories and then compress the whole directory.

Example :

```
@ECHO OFF
for /D %%f in ("C:\directory_with_files_you_want_to_compress\ *") do copy "C:\directory_with_readme.txt\readme.txt" "%%f\"
cd C:\directory_with_files_you_want_to_compress
SET PATH=C:;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Win dows\System32\Wbem;%PATH%
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /B') DO WinRAR a -m0 -ep -df -v100m -x*.rar "C:\where_you_want_to_save_new_rar_files\%%~nxd.ra r" "%%~fd"
EXIT
```

But it doesn't add `readme.txt` to the RAR files.

Answer (score 0):

That is very easy to achieve as console version `Rar.exe` as well as GUI version `WinRAR.exe` support multiple files or directories to be specified on command line to add into same archive file.

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("C:\directory_with_files_you_want_to_compress\*") do "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep -idq -m0 -x*.rar -v100m "C:\where_you_want_to_save_new_rar_files\%%~nxD.rar" "%%~fD\" "C:\directory_with_readme.txt\readme.txt" && rd /Q /S "%%~fD" || echo/ && pause
```

Same as above easier to read:

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("C:\directory_with_files_you_want_to_compress\*") do (
    "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep -idq -m0 -x*.rar -v100m -y "C:\where_you_want_to_save_new_rar_files\%%~nxD.rar" "%%~fD\" "C:\directory_with_readme.txt\Readme.txt"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        rd /Q /S "%%~fD"
    ) else (
        echo/
        pause
    )
)
```

The batch code uses console version `Rar.exe` instead of GUI version `WinRAR.exe` as there is absolutely no need for using GUI version for this archive files creation task.

The switch `-df` to delete all compressed files by *Rar* is removed because of `readme.txt` should not be automatically deleted by *Rar* after processing the first subdirectory. This file must be added also to the other archive files to create for the other subdirectories. Instead the command **RD** is used to delete the already successfully processed subdirectory. On an error like the RAR archive to create exists already and is write-protected an empty line is output with `echo/` and processing is halted with `pause`.

The switch `-idq` is added to run *Rar* in quiet mode which results in getting output only errors.

The switches `-m0` and `-v100m` results in just storing instead of really compressing all files in each subdirectory into a multi-volume RAR archive with 100 MB per volume. So this batch file is obviously used to pack already compressed archive, audio, image or video files into multi-volume archives.

The switch `-y` is added to automatically possible prompts with *yes*.

All switches are documented in text file `Rar.txt` in *WinRAR* program files folder.

I added after `%%~fD` a backslash in case of somebody else wants to use this code with switch `-ep1` instead of `-ep` and with adding the switch `-r` to recursively archive each subdirectory without having subdirectory name added to the archive too. The used switches archive only the files in each subdirectory, but not their subdirectories although the processed subdirectory is completely removed after creation of multi-volume RAR archive.

See also the answers on the questions:

- [Simply compress 1 folder in batch with WinRAR command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24401436/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)